# Return variable doesnt exist in context C#

Tags: c#, variables, recursion, return

an apology if this is a basic question, im new to this kind of stuff
i have the following code, in method Kep i need to calculate 50 times on a recursive way the operation that is inside and then after the 50 iterations return the value and print it.
when i try to run it it says that the variable doesnt exist on the context.
any suggestion is greatly appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kepler
{
    class Kepler
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Variables
            double M = 0; //Anomalia
            double e = 0; //Excentricidad
            double e0 = 0; //Excentricidad Corregida
            //double E1=0; 
            double E0 = 0; //


            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa M:");
            string m = Console.ReadLine();
            M = Convert.ToDouble(m);

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa e:");
            string ee = Console.ReadLine();
            e = Convert.ToDouble(ee);

            //Calculo de e0
            e0 = e * 180 / Math.PI;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa E0:");
            string EE0 = Console.ReadLine();
            E0 = Convert.ToDouble(EE0);

            //calculo de las funciones trigonometricas
            double sin = Math.Sin((E0 * Math.PI / 180));
            double cos = Math.Cos((E0 * Math.PI / 180));
            int cuenta = 0;

            Console.Clear();
            double total = Kep(M, e, sin, cos, e0, E0, ref cuenta);
            Console.WriteLine("Total=" + total);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static double Kep(double M, double e, double sin, double cos, double e0, double E0, ref int cuenta)
        {
            double E1 = 0;
            for (cuenta = 0; cuenta <= 50; cuenta++)
            {
                E1 = E0 + ((M + e0 * sin - E0) / (1 - e * cos));
                Console.WriteLine("E1 hasta ahora" + E1);
            }
            return Kep(M, e, sin, cos, e0, E1, ref cuenta);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will probably crash when you run it since you call the same function recursively without anything to stop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable `double E1` before the `for` loop, then assign it inside the loop. Make sure to initialize the variable to keep the compiler happy. Doesn't matter what value, as it will be overwritten in the first iteration.

Also, be aware that your `for` loop executes 51 times, not 50. If you want it to execute 50 times, change the `<=` in your for loop to just `<`.

Also, as Lior Raz pointed out (good catch), you need to add a stopping condition inside your `Kep` function, as the recursive calls will continue forever eventually resulting in a stack overflow.

Comment: thanks, i tried this but now it says 

Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'E1'

Comment: Give it an initial value to keep the compiler happy. `double E1 = 0;` ought to do it.

Comment: if i do that E1 will reset everytime to 0 (i think), and i need to know the value for each iteration

Comment: E1 will only be empty if there is nothing to loop

Answer (score 0):

Move the variable `E1` outside the loop, ie put it before the loop

The problem is it doesn't live in the same context as the return statement, it doesn't know it exists

i.e

```
// initialize E1 in the case cuenta is greater than or equal to 50
double E1 = 0;
for (cuenta=0; cuenta <= 50; cuenta++)
    {
        E1 = E0 + ((M + e0 * sin - E0) / (1 - e * cos));
        Console.WriteLine("E1 hasta ahora" + E1);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this but now it says 

Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'E1'